# How can I modify the server/client to take the port number and/or host as an optional command line argument?

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I want to use the default host name localhost and port 8080 when I don't specify the arguments.

server.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "command.h"
#include "send.h"
#include "receive.h"
#define DEFAULT_PORT 8080

void checkError(int status)
{
    if (status < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process %d: socket error: [%s]\n", getpid(),strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void handleNewConnection(int chatSocket);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   short int port;
   port = atoi(argv[1]); //When the argument is specified

(...)
```

client.c

```
(...)
void doLSCommand(int sid);
void doExitCommand(int sid);
void doGETCommand(int sid);
void doPUTCommand(int sid);
void doSIZECommand(int sid);
int  doMGETCommand(int sid);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    char fName[BUF_SIZE];


    char* host;
    short int port;

    host = atoi(argv[1]); //when argument specified in command line
    port = atoi(argv[2]); //when argument specified in command line

(...)
```

I used atoi to get the arguments when they're provided but I don't know how to set defaults if they are not provided.

Answer (score 3):

There are two arguments to the `main` function: `argc` and `argv`.

`argc` is a number of command line arguments passed and `argv` is the array of command line arguments.

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html

In your case, you can check the `argc` first for how many arguments has the user passed to your program and act accordingly.

So, for the host it could be:

```c
char* host;
if (argc > 1) {
  host = argv[1];
}
else {
  host = DEFAULT_HOST;
}
```

and for the port number:

```c
int port;
if (argc > 2) {
  port = atoi(argv[2]);
}
else {
  port = DEFAULT_PORT;
}
```